# Problem with compiling the code by terminal in linux

Tags: linux, gcc, terminal, compilation, virtualbox

I have a problem with compiling the code in the terminal. As in the photo, When I compile the code, it shows the same answer

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The file elnur.c is not saved, because it has (*elnur.c), the '*' sign means that the file is not save.

Save the file and run again.

Comment: When I change something in my code, I should save it again?

Comment: Yes, you need to save the file after every modification.When you compile the code with gcc, your file must to be saved.